# While automating login process with appium the password and username are entred in the same field of username

Tags: android, selenium, appium

Although the test is clear and simple i'm always facing the same problem while tring to send keys (username; password) the password field is written in place of username !

Here my Test NG i'm using appium for my tests

```
@Test
    public void Test1() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("newlook-tutoriel");
        driver.findElement(By.id("skip")).click();
        System.out.println("newlook-welcome");
        driver.findElement(By.id("btn_signin_welcome")).click();
        System.out.println("newlook-Me connecter");
        driver.findElement(By.id("input_email")).sendKeys("e@e.emma.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("input_password")).sendKeys("00000000");
        System.out.println("connected !!!!");
    }
```

> i got username = e@e.emma.com00000000

Comment: Interesting. Check again the id's of the fields both in the app and in the code and also check that they are unique in the page.

Comment: yes i check that it's fine

Comment: Which driver are you using, is it firefox?

Comment: i'm running an APK application on real device, so AndroidDriver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i have resolved this issue by adding to my code :

```
driver.hideKeyboard();
```

The issue was because the keyboard is hiding the field of password !

Comment: driver.hideKeyboard(); method throws exception if keyboard is not present. Better you handle it with Try catch block.

Comment: Then instead of hiding the keyboard you should scroll down to the actual field. That would reflect the expected user actions, which is the point of this kind of tests

Comment: Nice idea but the scroll is blocked because the name of the application should be visible !!

Answer (score 2):

This is strange issue. But Here is the solution for this.

```
public void hideKeyBoard()
{
    try{driver.hideKeyboard();}
    catch(Exception e){}
}
```

Use above method to hide keyboard

```
    driver.findElement(By.id("input_email")).click();

    driver.getKeyboard().sendKeys("e@e.emma.com");

    hideKeyboard();

    driver.findElement(By.id("input_password")).click();

    hideKeyboard();

    driver.getKeyboard().sendKeys("00000000");
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: @Emna Edited the answer. Check once again

Comment: I have already put my answer of keyboard before you and it works ok :D

Comment: i was already telling @acikojevic that the keyboard should be the origin of the problem 40 min ago !

Answer (score 0):

This could be timing issue, just for test try to put `Thread.sleep(5000);` after you set username and before you try to set password and see what happens.

It is strange but it happend in my case, sometimes my firefoxdriver wrote in wrong field even if all fields were unique and successfully found. Small time span between two `sendKeys()` calls solved the issue. I wasn't using sleeps, simple verification if correct text was written in the field between these 2 calls was enough time so that next `sendKeys()` writes in correct field.

Comment: Not likely, if timing was the issue it should have and error that element is not found or is not visible. It would be very strange to fill in a field with different id because of the timing.

Comment: i have to consider that keyboard is hidding the password field !

Comment: It is strange but it happend in my case, sometimes my firefoxdriver wrote in wrong field even if all fields were unique. Small time span between 2 sendKeys() calls solved the issue. I wasn't using sleeps, simple verification if correct text was written in the field between these 2 calls was enough time so that next sendKeys() writes in correct field. It's strange I agree. :D @Emna, did this temporary thread.sleep() help in your case?

Comment: No i removed Thread.sleep(5000); and put only hide keyboard it's working fine !

Comment: Thanks @acikojevic for your solution any way it can be helpfull in other cases !