# Not able to do login into Linkedin native app with appium

Tags: selenium, webdriver, appium

I want to do login with linkedin app using appium . Below is the code :
driver.findElement(By.id("session_keyoauth2SAuthorizeForm")).sendKeys("testmail@gmail.com"); driver.findElement(By.id("session_passwordoauth2SAuthorizeForm")).sendKeys("pswrd");

But I am not able to do as error coming that any element is not getting found.
Please suggest me why any element of linkedin app login page is not getting found while running test with appium.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change location strategy by `className` or by `cssSelector`

Comment: Now problem coming that both email and password are getting entered into same field email .So not able to enter password in password field.Please suggest any help for it.  Xpath for email apssword is : //android.widget.EditText[@index='0'] and //android.widget.EditText[@index='0']

Comment: just try to hide keyboard !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41977959/while-automating-login-process-with-appium-the-password-and-username-are-entred

Comment: i have tried by using hide keypad concept , its not working . Problem is that if i locate by id then error coming that element not getting located by using wait for visible element also.So i used custom xpath , for email xpath is "//android.widget.EditText[@index='0']" so its working but for password field assuming xptah "//android.widget.EditText[@index='1']" , its not getting located . So both fields not getting loacted with id and with xpath password field is not getting located . Any idea how to locate password field

Comment: Try to use all locations methods ! But i have a doubt that the field it self at the moment of locating an element is not ready ; u can try hide keyboard than wait for some seconds then try again !!! see answers for my question many suggestions are provided

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use x-path,
You don't have your logs, another possibility for Appium not being able to find the element could be, Elements are visible after the appium search. 
Use the wait for visibility and then perform the action on the element.

Answer (score 0):

Below code is working by method suggested by @Emna and using custom xpath for password field as below:

```
byXpath.click("//android.widget.EditText[@index='0']", "clicking login username field.");    driver.getKeyboard().sendKeys(value_LoginLinkedinUsername) hideKeyBoard();
Thread.sleep(5000);
byXpath.click("//android.widget.EditText[contains(@NAF,'true')]", "clicking login password field.");
   hideKeyBoard();
       driver.getKeyboard().sendKeys(value_LoginLinkedinPassword);
               hideKeyBoard();
```