# Not able to find locator in appium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium, python-appium

[image]I am new to appium python client and need your suggestions to solve my below issue.PFA uiautomator viewer[image] screen shot.Not sure if this is the reason: after typing into email field, a keyboard opens up so password and sign in button are not located
I have downloaded a free sample xxx.apk and created below script to test it:

```
class CareZoneAndroidTests(unittest.TestCase):
    "Class to run tests against the Care Zone app"
    def setUp(self):
        "Setup for the test"
        desired_caps = {}
        desired_caps['platformName'] = 'Android'
        desired_caps['platformVersion'] = '4.2'
        desired_caps['deviceName'] = 'Android Emulator'
        # Returns abs path relative to this file and not cwd
        desired_caps['app'] = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'D:/Programs/myapp/CareZone_v6.6.0.0 (flagship)_apkpure.com.apk'))
        desired_caps['appPackage'] = 'com.carezone.caredroid.careapp.medications'
        desired_caps['appActivity'] = 'com.carezone.caredroid.careapp.ui.activity.LandingActivity'
        self.driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)

    def tearDown(self):
        "Tear down the test"
        self.driver.quit()

    def test_login(self):
        "Test the Login Page launches correctly"
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(120)
        print "After WAIT----------------->>>>>>>"
        #Click on Sign in button
        element = self.driver.find_element_by_id("com.carezone.caredroid.careapp.medications:id/welcome_page_sign_toolbar_action")
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(15)
        element.click()
        element = self.driver.find_element_by_id("com.carezone.caredroid.careapp.medications:id/welcome_page_sign_mail_edit")
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        element.click()
        element.send_keys("abc@ini.com");
        element = self.driver.find_element_by_id("com.carezone.caredroid.careapp.medications:id/welcome_page_sign_password_edit")
        element.click()
        element.send_keys("abc");
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        #element = self.driver.find_element_by_id("com.carezone.caredroid.careapp.medications:id/welcome_page_sign_bton")
        #element = self.driver.find_element_by_accessibility_id('Sign In')
        element = self.driver.find_element_by_android_uiautomator('new UiSelector().text("Sign In")')
        element.click()
```

**Issue**:

> test_login (**main**.CareZoneAndroidTests) Test the Login Page
>   launches correctly ... After WAIT----------------->>>>>>> ERROR
>
> ====================================================================== ERROR: test_login (**main**.CareZoneAndroidTests) Test the Login Page
>   launches correctly
>   ---------------------------------------------------------------------- Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "D:\Programs\myapp\CareZoneTests.py", line 42, in test_login
>       element = self.driver.find_element_by_android_uiautomator('new UiSelector().text("Sign In")')   File
>   "D:\Programs\Python275\lib\site-packages\appium\webdriver\webdriver.py",
>   line 133, in find_element_by_android_uiautomator
>       return self.find_element(by=By.ANDROID_UIAUTOMATOR, value=uia_string)   File
>   "D:\Programs\Python275\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 752, in find_element
>       'value': value})['value']   File "D:\Programs\Python275\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 236, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "D:\Programs\Python275\lib\site-packages\appium\webdriver\errorhandler.py",
>   line 29, in check_response
>       raise wde NoSuchElementException: Message: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.

**Tried below but all are failing for the same reason:**

- ## element = self.driver.find_element_by_id("com.carezone.caredroid.careapp.medications:id/welcome_page_sign_bton")
- ## element = self.driver.find_element_by_accessibility_id('Sign In')
- element = self.driver.find_element_by_android_uiautomator('new
  UiSelector().text("Sign In")')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code worked fine for me:

```
class CareZoneAndroidTests(unittest.TestCase):
    "Class to run tests against the Care Zone app"
    def setUp(self):
        "Setup for the test"
        desired_caps = {}
        desired_caps['platformName'] = 'Android'
        desired_caps['platformVersion'] = '4.2'
        desired_caps['deviceName'] = 'Android Emulator'
        # Returns abs path relative to this file and not cwd
        desired_caps['app'] = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'D:/Programs/myapp/CareZone_v6.6.0.0 (flagship)_apkpure.com.apk'))
        desired_caps['appPackage'] = 'com.carezone.caredroid.careapp.medications'
        desired_caps['appActivity'] = 'com.carezone.caredroid.careapp.ui.activity.LandingActivity'
        self.driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)

    def tearDown(self):
        "Tear down the test"
        self.driver.quit()

    def test_login(self):
        "Test the Login Page launches correctly"
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(120)
        print "Sign in Page"
        element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='Have an account? Sign In']")
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(15)
        element.click()

        element = self.driver.find_element_by_id("com.carezone.caredroid.careapp.medications:id/welcome_page_sign_mail_edit")

        element.click()
        element.send_keys("ja.i@c.com");
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(3)
        self.driver.keyevent(61)

        element = self.driver.find_element_by_id("com.carezone.caredroid.careapp.medications:id/welcome_page_sign_password_edit")
        element.click()
        element.send_keys("ni");
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(3)
        print "Click TABS 2 times to get Sign In button-->>>>>>>"
        self.driver.keyevent(61)
        self.driver.keyevent(61)


        element = self.driver.find_element_by_id("com.carezone.caredroid.careapp.medications:id/welcome_page_sign_bton")

        element.click()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(120)
        print "TEST OK"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to find element by ID :

- element = self.driver.find_element_by_id('Sign In')

updated :

Try to put `hidekeyboard();` before doing the action of selection an element in order to hide your keyboard !

Comment: Thanks @Emna. What I have noticed is that when I type in email field, keyboard opens up in emulator. When driver tries to find password field or 'sign in' button, because of keyboard, locators are not found out.How can I solve this? Attaching screen shot of emulator

Comment: see my answer to this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41977959/while-automating-login-process-with-appium-the-password-and-username-are-entred

Comment: Thanks @Emna. I have added tab button and it solved my problem.